# How to calculate mix fraction in my java calculator?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, calculator

I have been working on this calculator for the past 2 months, and was not able to do the mix fraction calculation. At this point, I just want to know how i can make everything in my test run correctly. That means that mix fraction would give correct calculation. How would you do it? solution?

```
static int DO_DEBUG = 0;  // set to 1 for messages on, or 0 for messages off

    static final boolean BASIC_VERSION = false;


    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        calculator();
        //test();
    }


    public static void test() {
        String[] tests  = { 
                "1+1",
                "12 * 12",
                "1_1/2 * 1_1/2",
                "12 + mom",
                "12/3 / 3",
                "1_/3 + 5",
                "1 & 4",
                "12 +5",
                "1/3 - 1_4/5/6"
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( "TESTING: " + tests[i] );
            processInput( tests[i] );
        }

    }
    static void calculator() {

        Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in ); //turing input on

        System.out.println();
        String level = "Basic";
        if (! BASIC_VERSION ) {
            level = "Advanced";
        }
        System.out.println( "Welcome to the " + level + " Calculator");// have the option to pick basic or advance

        String input = "";
        while ( true ) {
            printPrompt();//this prompt is introduced in a different method
            input = console.nextLine();
            if ( isQuitRequest( input ) ) {//method to quit, says 'bye'
                break;//ends
            }
            processInput( input );// doing the task
        }
        System.out.println( "bye" );
        System.out.println( );
        console.close(); // quite keyword that closes console
    }

    static boolean isQuitRequest( String input ) {
        return input.equalsIgnoreCase( "quit" );
    }

    static void processInput( String input )  {

        if ( isQuitRequest( input ) ) { // if quit, does not reach here
            return;
        }

        String error = null;

        String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
        if ( tokens.length < 3 ) {
            error = "Not enough entires.";
        } else if (tokens.length > 3 ) {
            error = "Too many entries.";
        }
        if (error != null ) {
            printError( input, error );
            return;
        }

        String operator = tokens[1];
        String addition  = "+";
        String subtraction = "-";
        String multiplication = "*";
        String division = "/";
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
        double result;
        String number1 = tokens[0];
        String operation = tokens[1];
        String number2 = tokens[2];
        debug( "processInput: parse result number1='" + number1 + "' "
                + "number2='" + number2 + "' "
                + "operation='" + operation  + "'."
            );

        if ( (! isNumberValid( number1 ) ) 
                || (! isNumberValid( number2 )
                || ( operation.length() != 1 )
                || ("+-*/".indexOf( operation ) < 0 )) ) {
            error = "Syntax error.";
        }
            // If there is an error, print it,
            //  else print the parse results.
        if (error != null ) {
            printError( input, error );
        } else {
            //System.out.println( "Numbers are " + number1 + " and "
                //  + number2 + ".  Operation is " + operation +".");

            if (operator.equals(addition)){
                result = num1 + num2;
                System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
            }
            else if (operator.equals(subtraction)){
                result = num1 - num2;
                System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
            }
            else if (operator.equals(multiplication)){
                result = num1 * num2;
                System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
            }
            else if (operator.equals(division)) {
                result = num1 / num2;
                System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
            }
            else {

            }

                }
        }



    //just validating -_-
     static boolean isNumberValid( String  numstr ) {
         boolean isValid = true;
         if ( BASIC_VERSION ) {
             isValid = isValidInt( numstr );
         } else {    // ADVANCED version.
             isValid =  isValidMixedFraction( numstr );;
         }
         return isValid;
     }

    //This is to assure that everything entered is valid
     static boolean isValidInt( String  numstr ) {
         boolean isValid = true;
         for( int i = 0; i < numstr.length(); i++ ) {
            char c = numstr.charAt( i );
            if (! Character.isDigit( c )) {
                isValid = false;
            }
         }
         return isValid;
     }


     // formating of mixed numbers
     static boolean isValidMixedFraction( String  numstr ) {
         boolean isvalid = true;

            // get parts this string around the _
         String[] underscoreTokens = numstr.split("_");
         String firstPart = underscoreTokens[0];
         String secondPart;
         if( underscoreTokens.length == 1 ) {
             secondPart = null;
         } else  if( underscoreTokens.length == 2 ) {
             secondPart =  underscoreTokens[1];
         } else {  // underscoreTokens.length > 2 length matters
             return false;
         }


         debug( "isValidMixedFraction:  firstPart='"+ firstPart + "',  secondPart='"
                 + secondPart +"'" );        
         if (secondPart == null ) {
             // first part can be "n" or "n/n"
             if( (! isValidInt( firstPart ) ) && (! isValidFraction( firstPart )) ) {
                 isvalid = false;
             }
         } else {  // 2nd part not null.

             if  ( ! isValidInt( firstPart ) ) {
                 isvalid = false;
             }
             if  ( ! isValidFraction( secondPart ) ) {
                 isvalid = false;
             }
         }   // end else second part not null
         return isvalid;
     }

    //validating the format of the fraction if it is to be valid
     static boolean isValidFraction( String  numstr ) {
         boolean isValid = true;
            // get parts this string around the _
         String[] slashTokens = numstr.split("/");
         if( slashTokens.length != 2 ) {
            return false;
         }

         String firstPart = slashTokens[0];
         String secondPart = slashTokens[1];

         if ( ! isValidInt(firstPart) ) {
             isValid = false;
         }  else if (! isValidInt(secondPart) ) {
             isValid = false;
         }
         return isValid;
     }


     static void printError( String input, String error ) {//telling you what is wrong 
        System.out.println( "ERROR: " + error + "  for input '" + input + "'." );
    }

    static void printPrompt() {
        System.out.print( "> " );
    }

    static void debug( String s ) {// checking validality 
        if ( 0 < DO_DEBUG) {
            System.out.println( "DBG: " + s);}
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mix fraction"?  What problem are you having?  What is the expected output and what is the output you currently have?

Comment: 1_3/4 is 7/4 and that is 1.75. Then this can be multiplied, added, subtracted or divided.